# Measure sound input loudness on Linux

Tags: linux, audio, measurement

Is there a way to measure sound input loudness, specifically from a mike, in dB, on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

I think this website might point you in the right direction:

http://linux-sound.org/dsp.html